# Where does one grow nuts?

Tags: food

Are they grown in an orchard, or a grove? Is there another, more nut-specific term? I ask out of pure curiosity.

Comment: Depends on the nut: hazelnuts grow on bushes, not trees, and bushes don't get a nice group-planting term. That I know of. Closest I've encountered is "hazel thicket", but that makes it sound like somebody hasn't been pruning things properly.

Comment: Pecans and walnuts definitely grow in ***groves***

Comment: Nuts that grow on trees are grown in quantity in orchards: see the full definition of ['orchard'](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/orchard) at **Merriam-Webster**. Also, a simple web search for ["nut orchard"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=nut+orchard&t=canonical) returns many formal and semi-formal uses of the term.

Comment: Pine nuts grow in piñon pine forests. Peanuts grow underground.

Comment: I think the Internet grows nuts pretty well.

Comment: When I saw the title, I thought this was an opinion-based question about bravery.

Comment: In a crotch, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**nuttery** is the term you're looking for.

> :  a place where nut trees grow; also :  a place for storing nuts

[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nuttery)

Comment: "get thee to a nuttery'

Answer (score 1):

Almonds definitely can be grown in an orchard:

http://fruitsandnuts.ucdavis.edu/almondpages/AlmondOrchardManagement/

But you're right, I've never heard the phrase "nut orchard" or "nut grove" pronounced. With nuts, you've got to be specific, I suppose.

Also, money is said to grow on trees in some places.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible word is "plantation"

Comment: It may well be - can you offer some supporting evidence, like a published example of the word with specific reference to nut cultivation?

Comment: Well just going by the definition of the word it fits, also it is a word that includes tree crops like 'orchard'. Its not incredibly specific though.

I don't know what counts as a good source but there is lots of discussion of the term here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plantation#Orchards